# Ionic2 Deep linking segment optional params

Tags: angular, deep-linking, ionic3

I cannot find a single document that explains how to use optional params in segments.

In my app.module.ts I have this deepLinkConfig :

```
let deepLinkConfig = {
  links: [{
    component: HomePage, name: 'Home', segment: 'home'
  }, {
    component: ConnexionPage, name: 'Connexion', segment: 'connexion'
  }, {
    component: InscriptionPage, name: 'Inscription', segment: 'inscription'
  }, {
    component: ProfilePage, name: 'Profile', segment: 'profile/:userId'
  }, {
    component: ExplorePage, name: 'Explore', segment: 'explore'
  }, {
    component: FAQPage, name: 'FAQ', segment: 'faq'
  }]
};

...
imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, deepLinkConfig);
],
```

The user should be able to access his profile via `/profile`, but also consult another user's profile with `/profile/:userId`. But when I try to access /profile, I get an error :

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert

Via navCtrl, it's possible to go to 'profile' with an empty string as the userId, but once you actualize the page, it goes blank.

Is there a way to make the params optional in deeplinking ?

Comment: are subscribe to Deeplinks.routeWithNavController in appComponent? if not, here you can see how to do that https://github.com/ionicthemes/ionic2-socialsharing-with-deeplinking-example/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: No I didn't have to since I used another method. Edited OP so you can see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

This question has also been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478443/how-to-define-optional-segment-parameter-in-ionic-page) I think.

I know this is not so much of a solution I propose, but the only option that seem available at the moment will be to use a dummy value for the optional parameter, and to handle that in your code.
For example, the user would access it's own profile at `/profile/-` and other profiles at `/profile/anyOtherUser`.