# How to define optional segment parameter in Ionic Page?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How it is possible to define a optional parameter in Ionic 3 PWA?

My current `@IonicPage` decorator looks like:

```
@IonicPage({
    segment: "landing/:id"
})
```

But the `id` param must be optional. If I do not pass the `id`, I receive this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert

How to do it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There is no method yet.You need to send **empty string** when you don’t need it.That is the workaround for this now.

```
 this.navCtrl.push('landing', {
      'id': ''
    })
```

Comment: How do you do this in the template ?

Comment: there's a problem, that the path works, but when you refresh the page - it errors with `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for myPage: (?, ?, [object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

Since Ionic 4 with Angular: One solution is the resolution of different paths, here with two optional ids in URL:

```
{ path: 'landing', loadChildren: () =>
  import("./landing/landing.module").then(m => m.LandingPageModule)},
{ path: 'landing/:id1', loadChildren: () =>
  import("./landing/landing.module").then(m => m.LandingPageModule)},
{ path: 'landing/:id1/:id2', loadChildren: () =>
  import("./landing/landing.module").then(m => m.LandingPageModule)}
```

Allways the same target. The magic will begins in component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "landing",
  templateUrl: "./landing.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./landing.page.scss"]
})
export class landingPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let id1= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id1");
    let id2= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id2");

    // Test    
    if (id1) console.log(id1);
    if (id2) console.log(id2);
  }
}
```

And from page to page:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/landing');
this.router.navigateByUrl('/landing/' + '123');
this.router.navigateByUrl('/landing/' + '123/333');
```

The order is important and so is leaving the trailing slash on the first path.

Comment: I found this answer with a downvote and upvoted it, so now it's at zero. I guess the downvote was because the question was for Ionic 3 and the answer for Ionic 4, but for me, learning Ionic 6, was useful – and AFAIU it's still the way to go, or at lease, it's a very clear way to go :)